# mysql my.cnf is empty with webmin

Tags: mysql

mysqltune said that I need to make some changes in the my.cnf file

```
Variables to adjust:
query_cache_size (>= 8M)
tmp_table_size (> 16M)
max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
thread_cache_size (start at 4)
table_open_cache (> 400)
```

Anyway, if I go to /etc/my.cnf, this is what i get when I open the file

```
    [mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Where are located the parameters that I need to change? I've also opened every files under /etc/my.cnf.d/ but that parameters doesn't appear.

System: Centos 7
DB: MariaDB

any tips?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where are located the parameters that I need to change?

Create them, in the `[mysqld]` section.

Also, before doing this, please make sure you research and fully understand the configuration changes you're making. It is **never** advisable to make config changes based on an automated tool, no matter how reputable that tool is.